# A set with the same order structure as the ordinals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

The ordinals in set theory are well-ordered themselve, but do not form a set, but a class. But does there exists a set that has the same order structure as the ordinals?

Comment: What do you mean with "order structure"?

Comment: There is an order preserving correspondence, like a notion of isomorphism (but certainly as Ord is not a set we could have a map between sets).

Comment: A set is a bag of elements, there is no order in this bag.

Comment: Clearly there is no such correspondence, since it's impossible to have a bijection between a set and a proper class (axiom of replacement).

Comment: Such an ordered set would have cardinality at least as great as the cardinality of any set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

A set with the same structure as the ordinals would be well-ordered, and we know that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal. In particular, not to the class of ordinals.

However, it is not hard to show that if you just want to talk about an elementary substructures, then there are many ordinals which are themselves elementary substructures of the class of ordinals. Even if we add up the arithmetical operators of ordinals. In that sense, it means, there are many ordinals which are themselves with the same properties as the class of ordinals.